React Native | Ble Manager set notification failed
I'm trying to use startNotification from react-native-ble-manager without success
I'm using react-native (0.74 & 0.73.5) on Android to make bluetooth connection with react-native-ble-manager (tested on latest ^11.5.2 and oldest but no success), everything work (Connection, sending commands, scan,stop scan etc...) but the method to subscribe to notification fail.
I did the BleManager.start and added all required permission on AndroidManifest.
That's my react-native code :
<Button title="Connect" onPress={() => {
          BleManager.connect("AC:67:B2:5E:61:82")
            .then(() => {
              console.log('Connected');

              BleManager.retrieveServices("AC:67:B2:5E:61:82")
                .then((peripheralInfo) => {
                  // console.log("Peripheral info getted :", peripheralInfo);
                  console.log("Peripheral info charac :", peripheralInfo.characteristics);

                  BleManager.startNotification("AC:67:B2:5E:61:82", "0000A1B1-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB", "0000A3B3-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB")
                    .then(() => {
                      console.log('Notification started');
                    }
                    )
                    .catch((error) => {
                      console.log('Notification error', error);
                      console.log(error.reason);

                    });


                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  console.log('Connection error', error);
                });
            })

            .catch((error) => {
              console.log('Connection error', error);
            });
        }
        } />

And it result in connect/retrieve service success but error for startNotification :
Connected
Peripheral info charac : [{"characteristic": "2a05", "descriptors": [[Object]], "properties": {"Indicate": "Indicate"}, "service": "1801"}, {"characteristic": "2b29", "properties": {"Read": "Read", "Write": "Write"}, "service": "1801"}, {"characteristic": "2b2a", "properties": {"Read": "Read"}, "service": "1801"}, {"characteristic": "2a00", "properties": {"Read": "Read"}, "service": "1800"}, {"characteristic": "2a01", "properties": {"Read": "Read"}, "service": "1800"}, {"characteristic": "2aa6", "properties": {"Read": "Read"}, "service": "1800"}, {"characteristic": "a2b2", "properties": {"Notify": "Notify", "Read": "Read", "Write": "Write"}, "service": "a1b1"}, {"characteristic": "a3b3", "properties": {"Notify": "Notify", "Read": "Read", "Write": "Write"}, "service": "a1b1"}, {"characteristic": "a4b4", "properties": {"Notify": "Notify", "Read": "Read", "Write": "Write"}, "service": "a1b1"}]
LOG  Notification error Set notification failed for 0000a3b3-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
``
I already tested it with nrfConnect & property notify is here
